# Took ubuntu hard drive out of hp laptop and put it in a dell inspiron 1525 now I have no wifi

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch

I'm not familiar with ubuntu at all, I haven't the first clue about how to get my wifi to work now that I've changed laptops. As I have already said I don't know what I'm doing I only use internet explorers (Firefox) and word processing programs. I clicked the little icon for internet in the top right of the screen but it won't connect or even acknowledge that there's available wifi connections. If I plug it into the internet cord it will connect but that's it and I need to be able to take my laptop to other rooms.

Comment: So, your actual problem is that your wifi does not connect?  If you provide the diagnostic information discussed in this question you are much more likely to get detailed help.  Look at the answer titled  Wireless Info Script and provide the requested info by editing it into your question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the computer even has a WIFI module in it. If it does try to bring the driver back to the most basic driver then update it back up to the correct modern driver.

Comment: It had always connected to wifi when it had the other hard drive but it had gotten a virus so the hard drive was essentially a paper weight...how do I check for a wifi module? And how do I bring the driver back to the most basic?